# Is $X$ and $g(f(X))$ conditionally independent on $f(X)$?

Tags: independence, conditional-independence

Let $f,g$ be measurable functions and $X$ be a random variable.

Then, is $X$ and $g(f(X))$ conditionally independent on $f(X)$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because given $f(X)$, $g(f(X))$ is a constant random variable, and is independent of $X$.